# How to delete specfic text in a file using a perl one liner?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find some text in an XML file and delete only a part of a line that has it.
I found this format to try: `perl -p -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" $3` after some code searches.

So I'm using this code:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/\'../../../specialText/\'//g" "C:/box/fileName.XML";
```

What I want to do is delete everything from the inner single quotes as in:
**'../../../specialText/'**, but using q() or \' to escape the quote doesn't work and I'm not sure the ..'s aren't messing things up either.  I'm guessing that not putting anything in as a text replacement will delete it properly, but I'm not sure.

The errors are:

1. Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/specialText/\"
2. (Missing operator before \?)
   syntax error at -e line 1, near "/specialText/\"
3. Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

How do rewrite this one liner to accomplish this?

**This works.**

```
C:\box>perl -p -i.bak -e s/Copyright/bar/g Test.txt
```

I tried it on another file, so now I just have to play with it to modify my original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what's wrong with using another set of delimiters?

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s{'../../../specialText/'}{}g" "C:/box/fileName.XML"
```

Comment: I'm getting no such file or directory.  I'm using ActivePerl on a windows 7 box.  Is this a setup issue now?

Comment: Check the filename then, because the code works. ) Happened to me, btw, when tested this one-liner; turned out I confused .pl file with .pdf one. )

Comment: I put a semicolon ';' on the end pf the statement, which isn't needed when you run off the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the `.` and `/` characters in the search string by putting a backslash (`\`) before each of them.

However, to avoid acute [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), I'd recommend instead using alternative regexp delimiters and the `\Q` and `\E` [escape sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences), like this:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s(\Q'../../../specialText/'\E)()g" "C:/box/fileName.XML"
```